# CSS: displaying display:block elements inside display:inline elements

Tags: html, css

This code does what I want: `abc` is rendered next to `def`

```
<style type="text/css">
    div {display: inline;}
</style>
<div>abc</div>
<div>def</div>
```

This, however, creates problems:

```
<style type="text/css">
    div {display: inline;}
</style>
<div>
    <p>abc</p>
    <p>def</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>ghi</p>
    <p>jkl</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>mno</p>
    <p>pqr</p>
</div>
```

Because `p` still has `display:inline`, all the words are displayed vertically. There are other block level elements inside the div (e.g. `ul`) to consider, and arbitrarily many divs. I don't want to make `p` etc. inline because the desired effect is this:

```
abc ghi mno
def jkl pqr
```

How do I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `display:inline-block` for your `div`? Not really sure what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

write this in your css:

```
div {
  display: inline-block;
  *display:inline;/*for IE7*/
  *zoom:1;/*for IE7*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use class :

```
<style type="text/css">
     .inl {display: inline;}
</style>
<div>
    <p>abc</p>
    <p class="inl">def</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>ghi</p>
    <p>jkl</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do a simple

```
 <section id="floated">
     <div>
           <p>abc</p>
           <p>def</p>
      </div>
      <div>
           <p>ghi</p>
           <p>jkl</p>
      </div>
      <div>
           <p>mno</p>
           <p>pqr</p>
      </div>
 </section>
```

and then in the css

```
 #floated div {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 200px;
 }
```

This is just a quick-and-dirty answer, there are many possibilities to achieve what you are trying to do...

**EDIT**

another possibility:

```
 <div id="multicolumn">
     <div>
          <p>abc</p>
          <p>def</p>
      </div>
      <div>
          <p>ghi</p>
          <p>jkl</p>
     </div>
      <div>
           <p>mno</p>
           <p>pqr</p>
     </div>
 </div>
```

and the css:

```
 #multicolumn {
     -moz-column-width: 200px;
     -webkit-column-width: 200px;
     column-width: 200px;
 }
```

Like I said, there are tons of possibilities..

**EDIT 2**

You can see them both here: http://jsfiddle.net/ramsesoriginal/VZEsA/

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect the changes in the question. And to whoever downvoted: could you please gieve a reason for the downvote?

Comment: @ramsesorigianl; in your previous answer you give float to a one DIV instead of both DIV which is a wrong use of float.

Comment: In my previous answer there where only two div's. With two divs, one has to be floated, and the other one will be at it's side. With three div's that's not necessary since i switched to `display: inline-block`

Answer (score -1):

why not just use span tag instead of p tag?
because p tag will change to the new line